# Setting or extension to shrink lines of code that are empty or contain only brackets in VS Code or IntelliJ IDEs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea

There's a nice [extension in Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.SyntacticLineCompression2022) I've been using for years which shrinks the height of lines of code that don't contain alphanumeric characters. The left screenshot is with the extension installed, and the right is the standard behavior.

[image: 2]

I like this because it fits a bit more code onto my screen and makes debates about things like indentation styles and whether or not to use optional brackets less consequential.

Are there any settings or extensions available in VS Code or the Jetbrains IDEs that enable this same behavior?